# Panda's dataframe not throwing error for rows containing lesser fields

Tags: pandas, dataframe, validation, error-handling

I am  facing one issue when reading rows containing lesser fields my dataset looks like below.

```
"Source1"~"schema1"~"table1"~"modifiedon"~"timestamp"~"STAGE"~15~NULL~NULL~FALSE~FALSE~TRUE
"Source1"~"schema2"~"table2"
```

and I am running below command to read the dataset.

```
tabdf = pd.read_csv('test_table.csv',sep='~',header = None)
```

But its not throwing any error though its supposed too.
The version we are using

```
pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.0.1
```

My question is how to make the process failed if we will get incorrect data structure.

Comment: Can you explain why do you expect it to fail ? does different rows have different number of fields ?

Comment: When you instantiate a DataFrame pandas will consider missing values as ... well, missing values. You can handle those missing values (represented by NaNs) on your own or maybe try and use the on_bad_line argument to handle missing values.

Comment: Though `on_bad_lines=` only handles situations where there are too many fields - not too few.  Plus - `on_bad_lines=` became available in Pandas 1.3.  Like Luka mentions, the best approach would be to handle the NaNs after the data is read.

Comment: Hi @jch Thanks for the reply. But there are chances when value itself contain NaNs..Thats why i am facing issue to identify whether thats file structure problem or not.

Comment: Hi sayan dasgupta , yes exactly different rows can have diff number of fields. So i want the process should fail similar functionality like pyspark data frame failfast options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inspect the data first using Pandas and then either fail the process if bad data exists or just read the known-good rows.

**Read full rows into a dataframe**

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test_table.csv', widths=[999999], header=None)
print(df)

                                                   0
0  "Source1"~"schema1"~"table1"~"modifiedon"~"tim...
1                       "Source1"~"schema2"~"table2"
```

**Count number of separators**

```
sep_count = df[0].str.count('~')
sep_count

0    11
1     2
```

**Maybe just terminate the process if bad (short) rows**

If the number of unique values are not 1.

```
sep_count.nunique()
2
```

**Or just read the good rows**

```
good_rows = sep_count.eq(11)    # if you know what separator count should be. Or ... 
good_rows = sep_count.eq(sep_count.max())    # if you know you have at least 1 good row

df = pd.read_csv('test_table.csv', sep='~', header=None).loc[good_rows] 
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
         0        1       2           3          4      5     6   7   8      9     10    11
0  Source1  schema1  table1  modifiedon  timestamp  STAGE  15.0 NaN NaN  False  False  True
```